# Install Mojave 10.14.2 beta on a different partition

Tags: macos, mojave, beta

I wanted to test macOS Mojave 10.14.2 Public Beta so I downloaded and ran the macOS Public Beta Access Utility provided by Apple. However, I don't seem to have an option to download a full installer instead of directly upgrading to the beta. Do I really need to install 10.14.1 to a different partition and run the beta access utility from there to upgrade to 10.14.2? Is there a way to download the full installer for the beta?

**Current OS:** macOS Mojave (10.14.1)
**Hardware:** A hackintosh PC that works perfectly with macOS Mojave. I also have a Macbook Pro but I won't be installing the beta on it.

Comment: Have you enrolled in the beta testing program?

Comment: I don't have a paid developer account, I am enrolled to the Apple Beta Software Program and I only receive public betas.